# Repeat row of text by value in column?

Tags: python

I have such input (simplified to 4 columns; real data is quite huge) in tab delimited txt file:

```
FACTOR→NAME→SURNAME→ADDRESS
1→John→Smith→Chicago
3→Betty→Crawford→New York
2→Tom→Jonson→Chicago
```

And I want to get this:

```
FACTOR→NAME→SURNAME→ADDRESS
1→John→Smith→Chicago
3→Betty→Crawford→New York
3→Betty→Crawford→New York
3→Betty→Crawford→New York
2→Tom→Jonson→Chicago
2→Tom→Jonson→Chicago
```

In other words: I want to repeat each row based on value in `FACTOR` column. This value can have only `number > 0`. How can I do this in Python?

Comment: This is not the purpose of Stack Overflow. This is not ordering a working program by telling what it should do.
You should show some effort, try to do it and then, if you get stuck, ask for help with a more specific question.

Comment: You are right. I know how to do this with SQL on DB but I am very new to Python and what I did was only looping over rows to print them. Did not think that it was worth to post it. I will do so in future. But I see in what direction I should go i.e. use index of list in loop.

Comment: You need to show an attempt you've made in Python that didn't work and better define what you mean by "I want to get this"—what is "this" exactly? FWIW, you're statement about using the index of list in loop doesn't sound fruitful. All you need to use is the value in the `FACTOR` column as you said in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With script provided by Sam Chats I got this error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'FACTOR'
I guess it was because column name FACTOR was also used in loop as multiplying factor. I did some modifications to script and I got what I needed:

```
inp = open('input.txt', 'r')
out = open('output.txt', 'w')
header = inp.readline()
lines = inp.readlines()[0:]

out.write(header)

for line in lines:
    factor = int(line.split('\t')[0])
    out.write(line*factor)

inp.close()
out.close()
```

Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `output.txt` file for this, and considering the above mentioned lines as part of a `input.txt`, you can do something like:

```
inp = open('input.txt', 'r')
lines = inp.readlines()
inp.close()

out = open('output.txt', 'w')
for line in lines:
    factor = int(line.split('\t')[0]) #splits on tab and gets the leftmost value, converts it to int
    out.write(line+'\n'*factor) #this writes the line desired number of times
out.close()
```

Comment: That isn't going to work and circumventing the reputation restrictions isn't a good practice IMO—there's a reason for them.

Comment: @martineau I apologise; I've removed that line. By the way, what specifically did you mean when you said "That isn't going to work..."

Comment: If you don't see the problem(s), then perhaps you should try running the code and if you still can't figure it out, then ask post a question here—you don't need much reputation to do that.

Comment: Okay I'll do that, but I wasn't asking about errors. I was asking whether you meant errors or something more symbolic... like me adding that "I'm not allowed to" line :)

Comment: I meant fatal errors that will prevent it from working. FWIW, I almost always try running Python code I post in answers here. Since it's a dynamic  interpreted language, it's often impossible to detect problems until the code is executed (unless you have quite a bit of experience).

Comment: @martineau I've made the appropriate edits, it should work now.

Comment: Much better—even looks like it might work `;-)`. Suggest you read up on the [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) statement for future reference (because `file`s are context managers).

Comment: @martineau Oh thanks! I initially thought about using `with` here, but then I felt it would've made the answer a bit more complex.